# Orderby in generic list

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a generic list which I form from two other lists. The orderby doesn't seem to be working correctly. BeOrders come first (ordered by date) then BTOrders (ordered by date). Have I missed something obvious? I can't see anything wrong.

```
orders = new List<DataLayer.OrderStatusItem>();
orders.AddRange(BeOrders);
orders.AddRange(BTOrders);

orders.OrderBy(z => z.ordered);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you've missed that `OrderBy` doesn't order *in-place* - it *returns* an ordered sequence:

```
var inOrder = orders.OrderBy(z => z.ordered);
```

Or (assuming that `orders` is of type `List<...>`:

```
orders = orders.OrderBy(z => z.ordered).ToList();
```

Note that this "no side effects" approach is prevalent throughout LINQ - none of the operators change the collection they're called on; they return a view onto that collection of some form (filtered, projected etc).

If you want to sort a `List<T>` in place you can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx). (You'll have to specify the ordering in a different way though.)

Answer (score 7):

OrderBy returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, so you have to assign it to a variable:

```
orders = orders.OrderBy(z => z.ordered);
```